# What journal should I read for cutting-edge epistemology?

Tags: epistemology, reference-request

I'm a PhD candidate, but I still don't read many journals. Where should I start if I want to be up-to-date? One of my areas is epistemology, but this can be a more open ended question if need be.

Comment: @Carl great question! It might help if we get some context -- what have you found out, or what do you read already -- *Speculations*, *Collapse*...?

Comment: Agree with @Joe some more context would make this question eminently and relevantly answerable - are you looking for a survey article? What particular field are you interested in?

Comment: @Carl: the same ones your advisor, chair, and other members of your dissertation committee read! (This is only _partly_ tongue-in-cheek. Seriously, get to know what they're reading.)

Comment: @Ben and importantly, the same ones your advisor, chair and dissertation committee _publish_ in!

Comment: @Seamus: even better advice!

Comment: I'm at the University of Hawaii, so most of my current reading is in Asian philosophy journals, like Philosophy East & West, but I'm hoping to buff up my Western intellectual muscles.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the main journals would be Mind, Synthese, Erkenntnis. (This might just betray my Philosophy of Science bias though). Also worthy of note is the Oxford Studies in Epistemology.

Having said this, I don't think scouring new journal articles is the best place to start. You'll want to check out some recent "compendium" type volume of epistemology, like the Blackwell Guide to Epistemology. Once you've found your feet you should begin to get a feel for where your sort of stuff gets published by seeing where stuff you've enjoyed reading was published...